# Reordering groups of values per data frame row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a data frame with columns like:

```
x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1, z_0, z_1
```

Right now, that values can be anything, across x,y,z, there is no pattern.
For each row, I want to reassign the three letters (x,y,z) their value pairs (0, 1) from smallest "1" to largest "1".

Example Row (Parenthesis for readiability):

```
x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1, z_0, z_1

 (5    6)    (4    2)    (6    1)
```

Would become:

```
x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1, z_0, z_1

 6    1    4    2    5    6
```

I'm having trouble reading the docs to find a way to do this without it being really sloppy. It seems that when iterating rows I should not change the values, but that's what I want to do. When I try to search "reorder row values per row" on SO I still just get "reordering rows" results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your row in a 2D-array, sort it by the second column and reshape it back to a single row.

```
#This is your dataFrame:
columns = ["x_0", "x_1", "y_0", "y_1", "z_0", "z_1"]
data = np.array([5,6,4,2,6,1]).reshape(-1,6))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)

#Output
        x_0 x_1 y_0 y_1 z_0 z_1
  0      6   1   4   2   5  6

#Select your row, in this case row=0; get the values as a numpy array and reshape it to a 2D array
row=0
M = df.iloc[row].values
M = M.reshape(-1,2)

#Output
array([[6, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [5, 6]])

#Create a temporary dataframe that you can use to sort by second column (i.e. column 1)
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(M).sort_values(by=1)

#Output

    0   1
0   6   1
1   4   2
2   5   6

#Get the sorted values back to a numpy 2D array and reshape it;
df_temp.values.reshape(-1,6)

#Output
array([[6, 1, 4, 2, 5, 6]])

#And here you are
df.iloc[0] = df_temp.values.reshape(-1,6)

#Output
    x_0 x_1 y_0 y_1 z_0 z_1
0   6    1   4   2   5   6
```

You can put it all togheter in one line:

```
df.iloc[0] = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0].values.reshape(-1,2)).sort_values(by=1).values.reshape(-1,6)
```